# "Что ты, милая, смотришь искоса, низко голову наклоня?.."

Tags: грамотная-речь

А именно, интересует слово "наклоня". По идее ведь правильно "наклонив", да? Я понимаю, что тут взята такая форма для рифмы, но стало интересно, допустима ли форма "наклоня" в русском языке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допускаются обе формы, которые, скорее всего, различаются по стилю: наклонив (нейтр.) и наклоня (разг, поэт.)

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Обычно деепричастия совершенного образуются от основы прошедшего времени:
А)  с помощью суффикса В для основ на гласную:  сказать – сказав, 
Б) с помощью суффикса  ВШИ для возвратных глаголов:  умыться – умывшись,
В)  с помощью суффикса ШИ для основ на согласную: потрясти – потрясши.

В ЧАСТНЫХ СЛУЧАЯХ для образования деепричастий совершенного вида может использоваться основа простого будущего времени и суффикс А/Я: прочтут – прочтя, найдут – найдя.

А) В одних случаях эти деепричастия образуют ВАРИАНТНЫЕ ФОРМЫ: заметив – заметя,

Б) В  других случаях они являются БОЛЕЕ УПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬНЫМИ, чем формы с суффиксами В/ВШИ/ШИ: принеся, выйдя, зайдя, обретя, уведя.

В) Такие деепричастия часто используются в УСТОЙЧИВЫХ ВЫРАЖЕНИЯХ: сломя голову, спустя  рукава.

Answer (score 5):

> допустима ли форма "наклоня" в русском языке?

Только как разговорно-просторечная. В песенных текстах, посвященных например, деревенской тематике, было бы вполне уместно.

Подобные формы часто встречаются как устаревшие или диалектные.
И еще - в составе фразеологизмов, но "наклоня" к таковым не относится.

Тут другое.
Исходно песня (слова) была сделана Матусовским для **ленинградских** вечеров, в "подмосковные" срочно переделали под фестиваль молодежи и студентов 1957 г. (или, по другой версии, чуть раньше, под какой-то там ныне богом забытый фильм спортивной тематики). Но даже для Подмосковья такой просторечный выглядит инородным. Так что тут уважаемый Михаил Львович, проведший детство на Украине, имхо, "не попал".

Интересно другое. 
Популярность песни привела к тому, что "наклоня" стало некоторыми словарями стало признаваться едва ли не равноправным вариантом. Есть еще несколько подобных примеров, но этот, пожалуй, самый заметный.

Comment: "Их смуглые ручки порой подымали,И черные очи оттуда сверкали...
И, стан худощавый к луке наклоня, Араб горячил вороного коня" (М. Лермонтов. Три пальмы).

Comment: А вот не знаю...
Все дело в том, что современные деепричастия оформились в 60-х годах XIX века.